# Add partition projection to AWS Athena table using Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-athena

I have an Athena table defined with a template specified like so in cloudformation:

**Cloudformation Create**

```
EventsTable:
  Type: AWS::Glue::Table
  Properties:
    CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
    DatabaseName: !Ref DatabaseName
    TableInput:
      Description: "My Table"
      Name: !Ref TableName
      TableType: EXTERNAL_TABLE
      StorageDescriptor:
        Compressed: True
        Columns:
          - Name: account_id
            Type: string
            Comment: "Account Id of the account making the request"
            ...
        InputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
        SerdeInfo:
          SerializationLibrary: org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe
        OutputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
        Location: !Sub "s3://${EventsBucketName}/events/"
```

This works well and deploys. I also found out I can have partition projections created as per this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection-kinesis-firehose-example.html) and this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection-setting-up.html)

And can make that work with a direct table creation, roughly:

**SQL Create**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `performance_data.events`
(
  `account_id`  string,
...
)
   PARTITIONED BY (
     `day` string)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE
        'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
        'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
        OUTPUTFORMAT
          'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
    LOCATION
        's3://my-bucket/events/'
    TBLPROPERTIES (
        'has_encrypted_data' = 'false',
        'projection.enabled' = 'true',
        'projection.day.type' = 'date',
        'projection.day.format' = 'yyyy/MM/dd',
        'projection.day.range' = '2020/01/01,NOW',
        'projection.day.interval' = '1',
        'projection.day.interval.unit' = 'DAYS',
        'storage.location.template' = 's3://my-bucket/events/${day}/'
)
```

But I can't find the docs to convert into the cloud formation structure. So my question is, how can I achieve the partition projection shown in the SQL code in cloudformation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I now have a working solution. The missing piece was really a missing parameter, here is the solution:

```yaml
MyTableResource:
  Type: AWS::Glue::Table
  Properties:
    CatalogId: MyAccountId
    DatabaseName: MyDatabase
    TableInput:
      Description: "My Table"
      Name: mytable
      TableType: EXTERNAL_TABLE
      PartitionKeys:
        - Name: day
          Type: string
          Comment: Day partition
      Parameters:
        "projection.enabled": "true"
        "projection.day.type": "date"
        "projection.day.format": "yyyy/MM/dd"
        "projection.day.range": "2020/01/01,NOW"
        "projection.day.interval": "1"
        "projection.day.interval.unit": "DAYS"
        "storage.location.template":  "s3://my-bucket/events/${day}/"


      StorageDescriptor:
        Compressed: True
        Columns:
          ...

        InputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
        SerdeInfo:
          Parameters:
            serialization.format: '1'
          SerializationLibrary: org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe
        OutputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
        Location: "s3://my-bucket/events/"
```

The key addition was:

```
serialization.format: '1'
```

This now completely works and one can do a query that using the partition as:

```sql
select * from mytable where day > '2022/05/03'
```

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the CloudFormation [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-glue-table-tableinput.html) for the Glue Table `TableInput`, you can specify `PartitionKeys` and `Parameters`. This is the equivalent of `PARTITIONED BY` and  `TBLPROPERTIES` in the query.

#### EDIT

As an example, you can refer to this [article](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/glue/latest/dg/populate-with-cloudformation-templates.html). The sample below shows how to define the `PartitionKeys` and how to define a JSON for the `Parameters`. In your case, you just have to add the projection keys (such as `projection.enabled`) and values (`true`).

```yaml
# Create an Amazon Glue table
  CFNTableFlights:
    # Creating the table waits for the database to be created
    DependsOn: CFNDatabaseFlights
    Type: AWS::Glue::Table
    Properties:
      CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
      DatabaseName: !Ref CFNDatabaseName
      TableInput:
        Name: !Ref CFNTableName1
        Description: Define the first few columns of the flights table
        TableType: EXTERNAL_TABLE
        Parameters: {
    "classification": "csv"
  }
#       ViewExpandedText: String
        PartitionKeys:
        # Data is partitioned by month
        - Name: mon
          Type: bigint
        StorageDescriptor:
          OutputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
          Columns:
          - Name: year
            Type: bigint
          - Name: quarter
            Type: bigint
          - Name: month
            Type: bigint
          - Name: day_of_month
            Type: bigint            
          InputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
          Location: s3://crawler-public-us-east-1/flight/2016/csv/
          SerdeInfo:
            Parameters:
              field.delim: ","
            SerializationLibrary: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
```

Comment: Have an example of doing so?

Comment: @silverdagger edited the answer based on an example from the docs. It didn't have the projections yet, but you just have to add the key-value pairs in the JSON after `'classification' =  'csv'`.